# How to change ON expression in django-orm select_related()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

So i have this models

```
class ApplicationForHelp(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="applications", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(TagsForApplication, related_name="applications")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    is_anonymous = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    place = models.TextField(null=True)
```

And user model

so if do `ApplicationForHelp.objects.filter().select_related('user')`

what it does :
**left join ON application.user_id = user.id**

what i want :
**left join ON (application.user_id = user.id and application.is_anonymous=False)**

Comment: Is it not an option to do it on the filter?

Comment: @BrianDestura , not exactly. 

if i use filter(is_anonymous=True) .select_related('user')

i get only rows with is_anonymous=True

what i want is to get every application

but not to fetch user if is_anonymous=True

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the [FilteredRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects) objects says:

> FilteredRelation is used with annotate() to create an ON clause when a
> JOIN is performed.

Given `usernames`, an iterable of user names, and assuming one is looking for the `ApplicationForHelp` objects whose `user` foreign key has a username in `usernames` and whose `is_anonymous` field is `False`:

```
from django.db.models import FilteredRelation, Q
apps = (
    ApplicationForHelp.objects
    .annotate(
        not_anonymous=FilteredRelation(
            'user',
            condition=Q(is_anonymous=False)
        )
     )
    .filter(not_anonymous__username__in=usernames)
    .select_related('user')
)
```